# How to write css classes as per the specification provided?

Tags: css

Hi I am trying to write css classes as per the specification given. For example, If i am designing a button they have given specification as below.
Normal:-

[image]

Hover:-

[image]

Below is my html code which displays button.

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Button"/>
```

I want to write classes for the above button as per the specification provided. May i know how to write this? I have tried something below but correct me if i am wrong.

```
 .btn {
            background: rgb(12,116,218);
            border: rgb(12,116,218);
            border-bottom: rgb(0,76,151);
        }
```

Also how can I write css for the hover as per the above specification provided? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You'd probably better search the web for `css hover tutorial`, Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. Please see [ask].

Comment: He asked a simple question and provided code to review. He also showed examples on what he wants. This is better than 90% of new posts on SO.

Comment: Your class should be called "Primary", not "btn".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another rule with `:hover` selector

```css
.btn {
    background: rgb(12,116,218);
    border: rgb(12,116,218);
    border-bottom: rgb(0,76,151);
}
.btn:hover {
    background: rgb(46,146,250);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Button"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. In specification  they have given normal,hover,active and disabled option. So i need to write for each options like .btn:hover,.btn:active,.btn:noraml right?

Comment: Yes, more information about CSS selector can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS pseudo-selectors, also you can combine styles for multiple selectors (separated by coma)

```css
/* styles for the element */
.btn {
    background: rgb(12,116,218);
    border: 1px solid #0C74Da;
    border-bottom: rgb(0,76,151);
    
}

/* styling when on hover */
.btn:hover {
    background: rgb(46,146,250);
    border: 1px solid #2E92FA;
}

/* styles for both cases */
.btn, .btn:hover{
    font-size: 13px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Button"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write css as per below:

```css
.btn {
  background: rgb(12,116,218);
  border: rgb(12,116,218);
  border-bottom: rgb(0,76,151);
}

.btn:hover{
  background: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.btn:active { 
    background-color: yellow;
}

.btn:visited {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Button"/>
```

For better documentation  [check this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)